# Change cursor to Icon or fake a drag event

Tags: javascript, leaflet

What I want is for it to look like the user is dragging a custom icon from an outside control (.NET-based) into an embedded Leaflet map, for it to create a marker with that icon at the dropped position. I have the drop itself (icon created at drop point) working, but not the initial dragging the icon bit.

The ways I can think of to do this are:

1. Change the cursor within leaflet to be the dynamic icon being dragged
2. Make it so that the icon gets created and is already being dragged by the time the user scrolls their mouse over the Leaflet window.

[image]

Upon looking at #1, I can only find solutions to change the cursor to a collection of pre-defined types e.g. crosshair, which isn't what I want.

```
document.getElementById('map').style.cursor = 'crosshair';
```

I don't know enough about Leaflet or JS to know how to do #2.

Upon thinking about it, another solution may be:

3. Stop Leaflet from taking over the cursor while an object is being dragged from the external control. This would mean I can change the cursor icon in the external control. Leaflet would have to still be responsive to events during this time.

Comment: Can you rephrase the second point so even dumber, not native english speakers like me could understand, please?

Comment: @Kajbo the idea is: leaflet markers have a draggable property, so users can click and drag them around. Point #2 is saying that maybe I can fire a create and then a drag event when the user's cursor comes onto the leaflet screen from the outside control, so it's like they're already dragging the icon "from there." I'll add a picture to the question to hopefully help clarify it.

Comment: I do work with leaflet quite a lot, but I am not very familiar with dragging property, so my view might be incorrect, BUT I think this approach would be quite difficult - you'd have to capture x,y position of the mouse, compare it with size of leaflet container and, if person hovers over the leaflet, create new marker object and bind it to mouse. IMO better approach would be if you'd change cursor img to a picture when a user clicks item from the menu and create new custom marker on the leaflet where user clicks on.

Comment: @Kajbo Ok, do you know how to change the cursor image to a custom picture at run-time?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: @Kajbo so this looks like you can specify custom images for a cursor, but since I'm using a L.divIcon I don't think it works quite the same way as a normal cursor. In any case, for now I've done option #3 above, which is to completely disable the Leaflet cursor and let the external control set the icon. However, in the future when I want to be able to select and drag multiple icons at once, I think I will need to implement option #2.

Comment: Well, I guess you can also implement menu with draggable icons directly as leaflet control which might handle dragging over the map in some sensible way.